# Google Tag Manager for Xamarin Android app

Tags: android, google-analytics, xamarin, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

As of my googled data, i got to know how to integrate GTM with the xamarin app. Based the url [here](https://github.com/IdoTene/XamarinTagManagerAndroid).

The Tag manager is able to push the events to the GTM.

So question is, how to get the application data associated with GTM in the Google Analytics.

I get some links and videos while surfing for this, all are explaining about the GA for Web applications. Am looking the same for Xamarin Android application.

Edit:

- Adding to the question, Will GTM capture all the button clicks with out pushing the data?
- Will the data like 'submit button clicked' is transferred to GA via GTM?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an image and want to know how many people clicked on it. 
When the user clicks on the image you run this piece of code:

```
var dataLayer = new Dictionary <string, object> ();
    dataLayer.Add ("event", "imageClick");
    dataLayer.Add ("imageName", "Bart Simpson");

Android.Gms.Tagmanager.TagManagerClass.GetInstance (context).DataLayer.Push (dataLayer);
```

To get this data on GA through GTM you have to follow these steps on your GTM Container:

1. Create a new *TAG*
2. Choose **Google Analytics** as the product
3. Set the *GA's Tracking ID* and Track Type to **Event**
4. Set the *Category* to **{{Platform}}** (this will get *Android*)
5. Set the *Action* to **{{Event}}** (this will get *imageClick*)
6. Set the *Label* to a new Variable of the DataLayer type and named as  **imageName** (this will get *Bart Simpson*)
7. Set *Fire On* to **Any Event** (this will trigger everytime an event is pushed to GTM)
8. Save and publish your container

Now you can see the events popping in you GA Console. You can send multiple variables in one push, but you will have to create multiple Tags with different events to see them in GA.

Edit:

- No, you must push events to the DataLayer.
- Only if you configure the TAG as explained above.

On GTM there is basic tracking for web that is the same as inserting the google analytics tracking code on each page of your website, but that only works for basic stuff like page views, not custom events on buttons.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/ua)

Comment: As per this ans, we need to push the data to GTM to get tracked right?

Comment: Correct, but to make it available on GA you have to configure the TAG first.